# Sounds on Linux mint Firefox

Tags: audio, flash-player, linux-mint, firefox-3.6

I have Linux mint Helena, Firefox 3.6.10, and flash plug-in non-free 10.1.85.3Ubuntu0.9.10.1. I watched some videos in YouTube and everything was fine. Today I watched some videos and always the same thing: I can watch the video couple of seconds and the sound disappears suddenly. What might cause such a strange behavior?

---

```
jaakko@jaakko-desktop ~/Desktop $ lspci | grep -i Audio

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 02)

jaakko@jaakko-desktop ~/Desktop $ tail -f /var/log/messages

Oct 19 11:01:50 jaakko-desktop pulseaudio[1694]: ratelimit.c: 4 events suppressed

Oct 19 11:01:55 jaakko-desktop pulseaudio[1694]: ratelimit.c: 13 events suppressed

Oct 19 11:02:00 jaakko-desktop pulseaudio[1694]: ratelimit.c: 5 events suppressed

Oct 19 11:02:05 jaakko-desktop pulseaudio[1694]: ratelimit.c: 13 events suppressed

Oct 19 11:02:10 jaakko-desktop pulseaudio[1694]: ratelimit.c: 11 events suppressed

Oct 19 11:02:15 jaakko-desktop pulseaudio[1694]: ratelimit.c: 7 events suppressed

Oct 19 11:02:20 jaakko-desktop pulseaudio[1694]: ratelimit.c: 6 events suppressed

Oct 19 13:48:12 jaakko-desktop kernel: [564016.908196] plugin-containe[18484] general 
protection ip:21e35f sp:f74061f7 error:0 in libc-2.10.1.so[1f4000+13e000]

Oct 19 15:38:16 jaakko-desktop sudo: pam_sm_authenticate: Called

Oct 19 15:38:16 jaakko-desktop sudo: pam_sm_authenticate: username = [jaakko]
```

I have no caches in my home folder as far as I remember.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you give some more informations like the output of:
lspci | grep -i Audio
and
run this command when the sound disappeared and post the output:
tail -f /var/log/messages

You can also reset your alsa confguration or clearup some configuration/temporary/cache files in your home folder